# Visual analytics on bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot, ibm-cloud-plugin

How can I run visual analytics on historical IoT data on #Bluemix?
There are services like Real-time Insights and Streaming analytics for real-time data analytics, but is there a service for historical data analytics and visualization?

Comment: How is your data stored?  Are you using the IoT framework, Cloudant or some other means?  Knowing that can help us recommend a method to better visualize historical data.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different options depending on your use case, experience and data source.  For example:

- You can use Jupyter notebooks or RStudio on [Data science experience](http://datascience.ibm.com). You can use R, python or scala to analyse data and create re-runnable reports. You can also use spark which is great if your data volumes are large or you want to use spark's vast number of connectors to different data sources.  This approach is ideal for data scientists with coding experience.
- You can use [Watson Analytics](https://www.ibm.com/analytics/watson-analytics/us-en/) if you want to do analysis without data science or coding skills.  This environment is more for ah-hoc analysis rather than reporting.
- If you are looking to do reporting [Cognos](https://www.ibm.com/uk-en/marketplace/business-intelligence) has excellent visualization capabilities and reports can be created by users who don't have coding skills.

There are a number of other options, but in my experience the above three tend to be the most common.